# CSS circle not showing up

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a circle from CSS, but it does not appear on the website. Could anyone shed some light on my situation?

[Link to JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/zx9p94fa/)

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
    color: black;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: see this site http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp ('Draw a Circle' section) to learn how to draw a circle using HTML5

Comment: did you import the css? show us your html header. you are not closing your div as well.

Comment: @hmtareque I've linked the CSS file, as I am using it for other parts of the website. It's also not an issue with z-index, so I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`color` should be `background-color`:

```
.circle {
background-color: black;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
border-width: 5px;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zx9p94fa/2/)